# Strip outside quotes from text when writing to list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text file that looks like this when opened as file:

```
'element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4'
```

I then use a list comprehension to read this into a list

```
thelist = [line.strip() for line in open('file.txt', 'r')]
```

But the list looks like this with only one element at index 0

```
["'element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4'"]
```

Since the double quotes are appended to the ends of the first and last elements, python thinks it is a single element list. Is there a way to use the "strip()" inside the list comprehension to remove those outside double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a list, you have a string that looks like a Python sequence.

You could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to interpret that as a Python literal; it'll be parsed as a tuple of strings:

```
import ast

thelist = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in open('file.txt', 'r')]
```

or you could just split on the comma, then strip the spaces and quotes:

```
thelist = [[elem.strip(" '") for elem in line.split(',')]
           for line in open('file.txt', 'r')]
```

This only works if your quoted values don't themselves contain commas.

Either way you get a list of lists; you could flatten that list:

```
thelist = [elem for line in open('file.txt', 'r')
                for elem in ast.literal_eval(line)]
```

or just read the *one line*:

```
thelist = ast.literal_eval(next(open('file.txt', 'r')))
```

You could also use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(
    open('file.text', 'rb'),
    quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
thelist = list(reader)
```

or for the first row only:

```
thelist = next(reader)
```

Comment: both these methods suffer from the same problem.  If I type thelist[0] in the interpreter I get all of the elements

Comment: @Cybernetic: yes, because now you have a list of lists.